# What is the difference between a CPU and a GPU oriented code?

Tags: game-engine

Let us suppose a game developer develops an application. So, while writing the application will the developer write some code segment which should goto CPU and some which should goto GPU or is decided by scheduler at run time?

Comment: Read tag-descriptions before adding! This is not related to embedded. And as given it is language-agnostic.

Answer (score 4):

CPUs and GPUs are different, optimised to do different things. GPUs are less clever, but massively more parallel and carry out a huge amount of specialised processing, as opposed to the traditional CPUs more general processing.

GPUs have to be tasked by the CPU. No scheduler run time devisions are possible, because they are different, capable of different instructions.

Comment: In the case of nVidia's PhysX, the choice between CPU and GPU can be selected by the user via the control panel, including an automatic setting, so for some programs that use that setting, the choice is made at runtime.

Comment: That's interesting... there's no reason why anything done on the GPU can't be done on the CPU... but, though I don't know anything about this capability, I would have to assume that what the control panel is doing is flipping a bit, such that certain operations/calls are fulfilled by 2 different implementations, one utilising the CPU and one a GPU, but to be clear, but these would be 2 essentially different bits of code, not the same code rescheduled.

Comment: The only game I have that uses PhysX always selects CPU, or at least that's what is displayed at the in game setting (the control panel also has an option to display the current setting as an overlay), so I don't how many games actually use this option, but it is there in the control panel.

Comment: how does CPU decide which task has to be sent to GPU ?

Comment: It is programmed. The developer who writes the code that runs on the CPU also writes the code that will run on the/a GPU, and writes the interface between the two processors. It's all very explicit. The developer must cater for the cases that there is no GPU of course (by cater I mean ideally not just crash) and take into account that some GPUs have different capabilities, and also consider that there may be more than one GPU, each different.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have tagged `C`, let me tell you that any program you write in C and compile using `GCC` or any compiler is aimed for your CPU.

If you code something and compile it with a regular compiler, that's not targeted for GPU execution, the code will always execute at the CPU.

The calls made to your graphics library are "executed" by your CPU, however the graphics oriented calls (example, drawing something) are operated by your GPU.

Further, answering this depends on what language and programs you are executing. CUDA and OpenCL, or OpenGL compute shaders are executed at GPU.

So basically, all the program execution of your code, that is setting up the compiler environment for rendering calls in your code is done by CPU.

Answer (score 3):

CPU and GPU are very different and have different programming models and programming languages. You could use C on the CPU and [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) (or [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA), if you restrict yourself to Nvidia products) on the GPU.

You generally won't be able to run an arbitrary C code on the GPU.

Coding for GPUs is painful, and you have to tune the code to the particular hardware.

See also tools like [PIPS4u](http://pips4u.org/) & [OpenACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC)